# Define equivalence classes for $\tan(x)+k=\tan(y)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let $ x,y \in \mathbb{R}, x\sim y \iff \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}\  \tan(x) + k = \tan(y)$  be equivalence relation. Define equivalence classes.
I understand that equivalence classes for $x$ are such $y$ that $\tan(y) - k = \tan(x)$.
But is there a way to express $x$, and classes for it (I don't think that $\cot$ has to to something with it here)?

Comment: The class containing zero is all numbers of the form $\arctan k+m\pi$, where $k$ and $m$ are integers. I think that's about the best kind of expression you're going to get.

Comment: @GerryMyerson what do you mean by containing zero?

Comment: What do *you* mean by "equivalence class"? An equivalence class is a set. Sets contain elements. That's what I mean by "containing zero".

Comment: @GerryMyerson you mean when x = 0?  Then what about other cases?

Comment: Well, what about the other cases? Can you figure it out?

Comment: @GerryMyerson well, as i see x is R so there are infinite number of x and we cant give classes for each, so we can define it by some formula.  But i can`t express x out of this equality.

Comment: You're not thinking. Suppose $x=17$. What do you get when you solve for $y$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson i get such y,  tangents of which - some integer = tangent of x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalence *class* is a set $S\subseteq \mathbb R$ where $a=b$ if and only if $a,b \in S$.

Often, it's useful to identify the classes via a representative element. For example, the smallest non-negative member, if that exists.

Then, you can try and define the other members *constructively* from that one. For example, via a function like $f(x,i,\dots)$. $i, j, \dots$ that parameterize the class. Ideally, there should be a 1-1 relationship between those parameters and members -- each member is uniquely identified.

The definition you are given is implicit: it's not a function that gives you other members of the class.

$k$ seems like a useful parameter to start with. So, you find all solutions $y$ in terms of $x$ and $k$:$$
y=f(x,k,n)=\arctan (\tan x+k) + n\pi
$$

The "smallest non negative member" way of identifying a representative member seems reasonable: we can use $x \in [0, \tfrac \pi 4)$. Because $\tan \tfrac \pi 4=1$, we can see that $\tfrac \pi 4$ is in the same class as $0$.

Because $\tan$ is periodic, $n$ emerges as an additional parameter. Because of the limited range of $\arctan$, and its monotonicity, you can easily see that no two $(k,n)$ produce the same $y$. Since the domain of $\arctan$ is $\mathbb R$, all $k$ lead to a valid result.

So an equivalence class and its members are nicely parametrized by two integers, given $x\in[0, \tfrac \pi 4)$.

Comment: “$a=b$ if and only if $a,b \in S$” can be confusing to someone who is learning about equivalence classes.

Comment: Can you think of a better way of putting it? Or should I just scrap it?

Comment: @AlexK Thanks sp much!  but,  I have one question : in one equivalance class the 'k' has to be the same for all elements?

Comment: No -- $x$ is the same, but $k$ and $n$ can change. So $x$ tells you what class, and $k$ and $n$ identify elements within one class

Answer (score 1):

Each element of a specific equivalence class will be congruent to $(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is some real number such that $0 \leq \theta < \pi/4$.

This is because $\tan(0) = 0$ and $\tan(\pi/4) = 1.$

That is, as $\theta$ ranges from $0$ (inclusive) to $\pi/4$ exclusive, $\tan(\theta)$ takes on all values between $0$ inclusive and $1$ (exclusive).  So, for any real number $y$, there will have to be a **unique** $\theta$ such that $0 \leq \theta < \pi/4$ and the **fractional** part of $\tan(y)$ equals $\tan(\theta).$

**Note**:
If (for example) $\displaystyle ~\tan(y) = -\frac{7}{3} = -3 + \frac{2}{3},$ 
then I am interpreting the fractional part of $~\tan(y)~$ to be $~\dfrac{2}{3}.$

So, you can let $\{\theta ~: 0 \leq \theta < \pi/4\}$ represent the set of all equivalence classes.